# how to convert spreadsheet cells to units of time?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

This is the goal:

```
   +------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+
   | A    |        B            | C       |        D            |
   +------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+
1  | Joe  | 2016/04/01 00:00:00 | 15      | 2016/04/01 00:15:00 |
   +------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+
2  | Rick | 2016/07/01 00:10:15 | -6      | 2016/07/01 00:04:15 |
   +------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+
```

D1 = B1+C1

How do I define a cell as 'minutes' or 'hours' but not a full 'time' or 'date' entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula would be

```
=B1 + C1/(24*60)
```

As Excel denotes time as a decimal based on 24 hours being 1.

[image]

Comment: Thanks again. I didn't realize it was that simple. Check out my formula. This considers that the H column contains a number in hours

`=IF(H2<1,CONCATENATE(ROUND(H2*60,2)," Minutes"),IF(AND(H2>=1,H2<24),CONCATENATE(ROUND(H2,2)," Hours"),IF(H2>24,CONCATENATE(ROUND(H2/24,2)," Days"))))`

Comment: @Benjamin or you could simply use `=H2/24` and use a custom number format of `d \D\a\y\s h \Hou\r\s m \Mi\nut\e\s`  It would put 0 in front of days and Hours if there are none.

Comment: @Benjamin so for example if H2 had `0.5` then the result would be `0 Days 0 Hours 30 Minutes`

Comment: oh, that's really cool, too. so many options\